# Copy UICollectionView already created in IB

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, copywithzone

I am trying to copy a collectionView I did in IB. Is there any quick way I could use to have a deep copy of the collectionView instead of creating it in my code programmatically and adding the cell views.

**Update 1** : UICollectionView created in my storyboard

Comment: If you mean that you want to have a reference to it in your code than linking it with an outlet should be your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576515/how-do-i-connect-a-iboutlet-to-a-uiview

Comment: Define copy in this context.

Comment: Did you use it inside storyboard? because if so you can't use it.
You need to export the uicollectionview and the uicollectionviewcell to a xib file to reuse it in other ViewController

Comment: @JadFeitrouni No I have a reference for it in my code thats not my problem.

Comment: @wain I mean copy as in have an array of it for example (Array of the collectionView I created in my storyboard with several references).

Comment: @Blacky Yes its still in my storyboard. Can you please point me somewhere I could look further into this so I can place it in my xib and use it from there.

Comment: What would you use an array of collection views for?

Comment: @Wain Im trying to create something like the iPhone springboard... Several CollectionViews stacked next to each other and by swiping I could switch from one collection to another just like the iPhone springboard. Here is my previous question concerning this matter : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250695/several-uicollectionviews-scroll-horizontally-like-ibooks)

Comment: You should not create duplicate questions...

Comment: Why not to use one collection view to handle all the rest?
UICollecitonViewCell can be a collectionView and the super collection view  will be with paging enabled...